Trying to recreate this progressive blur tab bar in SwiftUI but I am struggling
I'm trying to recreate this progressive blur tab bar in SwiftUI but I am struggling. I'm using this library for the progressive blur: Glur - progressive blur library
I have attached my code and images of the tab bar I'm trying to recreate plus an image of my attempt.
[progressive blue tab bar example 1]
[progressive blue tab bar example 2]
My attempt
import SwiftUI
import Glur

struct CustomTabBar: View {
    @Binding var selectedTab: Int
    
    let tabs = [
        ("photo", "Photos"),
        ("clock", "Recents"),
        ("globe", "Explore"),
        ("person.2", "Sharing"),
        ("person.crop.square", "Profile")
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(0..<tabs.count, id: \.self) { index in
                Spacer()
                TabBarItem(imageName: tabs[index].0, isSelected: selectedTab == index)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        selectedTab = index
                    }
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .padding(.top, 10)
        .background(
            Rectangle()
                .fill(.ultraThinMaterial)
                .glur(radius: 20, offset: 0.5, interpolation: 0.5, direction: .up)
                .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .bottom)
        )
    }
}

struct TabBarItem: View {
    let imageName: String
    let isSelected: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: imageName)
            .font(.system(size: 24))
            .foregroundColor(isSelected ? .black : .gray)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedTab = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            // Your main content here
            Color.white.ignoresSafeArea()
            
            CustomTabBar(selectedTab: $selectedTab)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}


Welcome to Stack Overflow! It may be obvious to yourself what you are asking for, but it's hard to tell what exactly you need. Please try to describe (in words) what you expect to see and what you want to achieve.

So, as the main content is scrolled behind the custom tab bar, you want the content to become progressively blurred? This will be difficult with SwiftUI. What you can do is apply a gradient opacity mask to the Material background, but this only provides progressive opacity, not progressive blurring.
